# i want learn ''production sound mixing'' for film, particularly everything about the field mixer and what it can do for me. any DVD/book tutorial?

Tags: production, mixer, mixing, production-mixing

i know how to use boom, microphone, cable and all its function to its best. but when i use 2microphone or more i don't know how to operate my field mixer. actually i don't know anything about mixer. i want learn properly about this. please anyone suggest me a good DVD or book that will teach me... (i already done the search i cannot find a good book or DVD to learn detail about this)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a search using button on the first page first. Lots of similar posts can be found here.

Answer (score 1):

This site has a lot of good info on this topic. You may want to read up in the DVX user forums as well as purchase some recommended reading posted throughout the Internet sites including this one. The best possible way to learn is to rent the equipment or offer your time as a cable person / utility to established mixers and learn from them. Best of luck.

Comment: Jay Rose has some books on the subject, just search "production sound mixing" etc.. Goto dvxuser forums sound section, read the stickies.

Answer (score 0):

This book : http://www.trewaudio.com/store/product.php?productid=1120&cat=149&page=1 is a very valuable source of real world information. No bullshit here :)

Answer (score 0):

I second Matt. Can't stress enough the value in being able to shadow someone experienced. While I was lucky enough to study sound in film school, I'd say 80% (if not more) or my knowledge was acquired by getting out there and working - which, needless to say, frequently means working utility for little to no money while you learn the ropes. If you know of anyone in the field, give them a shout - mixers are frequently looking for a cable person and are usually more than willing to show you the ins and outs when time allows on location. Time spent on set with a working professional is invaluable; you'll learn more on a couple shoots with a friendly pro than you ever could with books/dvds alone. Put in the hours and you'll get there. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Check out www.pro-sound.com. Rich Topham gives free seminars on the basics of sound mixing all the time. Also their newsletter each month has great advise.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ricviers.com/#!location-sound-bible/c1zb6 is one of the best books around for learning about location sound and production sound mixing.